# Replace missing values (NA) with most recent non-NA by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I would like to solve the following problem with dplyr. Preferable with one of the window-functions.
I have a data frame with houses and buying prices. The following is an example:

```
houseID      year    price 
1            1995    NA
1            1996    100
1            1997    NA
1            1998    120
1            1999    NA
2            1995    NA
2            1996    NA
2            1997    NA
2            1998    30
2            1999    NA
3            1995    NA
3            1996    44
3            1997    NA
3            1998    NA
3            1999    NA
```

I would like to make a data frame like this:

```
houseID      year    price 
1            1995    NA
1            1996    100
1            1997    100
1            1998    120
1            1999    120
2            1995    NA
2            1996    NA
2            1997    NA
2            1998    30
2            1999    30
3            1995    NA
3            1996    44
3            1997    44
3            1998    44
3            1999    44
```

Here are some data in the right format:

```
# Number of houses
N = 15

# Data frame
df = data.frame(houseID = rep(1:N,each=10), year=1995:2004, price =ifelse(runif(10*N)>0.15, NA,exp(rnorm(10*N))))
```

Is there a dplyr-way to do that?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

These all use `na.locf` from the zoo package.  Also note that `na.locf0` (also defined in zoo) is like `na.locf` except it defaults to `na.rm = FALSE` and requires a single vector argument.  `na.locf2` defined in the first solution is also used in some of the others.

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

na.locf2 <- function(x) na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE)
df %>% group_by(houseID) %>% do(na.locf2(.)) %>% ungroup
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
Groups: houseID

   houseID year price
1        1 1995    NA
2        1 1996   100
3        1 1997   100
4        1 1998   120
5        1 1999   120
6        2 1995    NA
7        2 1996    NA
8        2 1997    NA
9        2 1998    30
10       2 1999    30
11       3 1995    NA
12       3 1996    44
13       3 1997    44
14       3 1998    44
15       3 1999    44
```

A variation of this is:

```
df %>% group_by(houseID) %>% mutate(price = na.locf0(price)) %>% ungroup
```

Other solutions below give output which is quite similar so we won't repeat it except where the format differs substantially.

Another possibility is to combine the `by` solution (shown further below) with dplyr:

```
df %>% by(df$houseID, na.locf2) %>% bind_rows
```

**by**

```
library(zoo)

do.call(rbind, by(df, df$houseID, na.locf2))
```

**ave**

```
library(zoo)

transform(df, price = ave(price, houseID, FUN = na.locf0))
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

data.table(df)[, na.locf2(.SD), by = houseID]
```

**zoo** This solution uses zoo alone.  It returns a wide rather than long result:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(df, index = 2, split = 1, FUN = identity)
na.locf2(z)
```

giving:

```
       1  2  3
1995  NA NA NA
1996 100 NA 44
1997 100 NA 44
1998 120 30 44
1999 120 30 44
```

This solution could be combined with dplyr like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% read.zoo(index = 2, split = 1, FUN = identity) %>% na.locf2
```

**input**

Here is the input used for the examples above:

```
df <- structure(list(houseID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), year = c(1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
  1999L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 
  1998L, 1999L), price = c(NA, 100L, NA, 120L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
  30L, NA, NA, 44L, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("houseID", "year", 
  "price"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

**REVISED** Re-arranged and added more solutions.  Revised dplyr/zoo solution to conform to latest changes dplyr.  Applied fixed and factored out `na.locf2` from all solutions.

Comment: I have shown the output I get near the botom.  Try grabbing the latest version of dplyr in case its your version of dplyr that is causing problems: `devtools::install_github("haldey/dplyr")`

Comment: I tried your code and got the error: Error in na.locf(.) : object '.' not found. I am working on a server and can not change dplyr-version on the fly (It is 2 month old).

Comment: Here is the `by` solution reworked to use dplyr:  `df %.% by(df$houseID, na.locf) %.% do.call(what = rbind)` .  If none of these dplyr solutions work for you, likely because of your old version, then use one of the other solutions I have provided.

Comment: This on works: df %.% group_by(houseID) %.% mutate(p2 = na.locf(price,na.rm=F))

Comment: I have added a second dplyr solution which combines the `by` and the dplyr solutions and may (or may not) work with your older version of dplyr.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very impressive!

Comment: Since there are many way to do this, one criterion to choose the best approach is speed. I have tested zoo, dplyr and data.table solutions; in my experience the fastest is data.table.

Comment: Other ways are readability, conciseness, simplicity and lack of dependencies.

Comment: how to only apply {na.locf} to selected column,say price (assuming year has missing values too).This your example: df %>% group_by(houseID) %>% na.locf %>% ungroup

Comment: Use mutate as in the comment by @Peter S.

Comment: The first solution has the problem of filling in from the previous group if the first value in a group is NA. For example, `data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2), y=c(1:3, 2,3), z=c(4:6, 1,2)) %>% group_by(x) %>% complete(y=1:3) %>% na.locf(na.rm=FALSE)` fills in the `z` column with 6 when it should be undefined (i.e., `NA`)

Answer (score 84):

`tidyr::fill` now makes this stupidly easy:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
# or library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(houseID) %>% fill(price)
# Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
# Groups: houseID [3]
# 
#    houseID  year price
#      (int) (int) (int)
# 1        1  1995    NA
# 2        1  1996   100
# 3        1  1997   100
# 4        1  1998   120
# 5        1  1999   120
# 6        2  1995    NA
# 7        2  1996    NA
# 8        2  1997    NA
# 9        2  1998    30
# 10       2  1999    30
# 11       3  1995    NA
# 12       3  1996    44
# 13       3  1997    44
# 14       3  1998    44
# 15       3  1999    44
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do a rolling self-join, supported by `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)   ## change it to data.table in place
setkey(df, houseID, year)     ## needed for fast join
df.woNA <- df[!is.na(price)]  ## version without the NA rows

# rolling self-join will return what you want
df.woNA[df, roll=TRUE]  ## will match previous year if year not found
```

Answer (score 8):

Pure dplyr solution (no zoo).

```
df %>% 
 group_by(houseID) %>%
 mutate(price_change = cumsum(0 + !is.na(price))) %>%
 group_by(price_change, add = TRUE) %>%
 mutate(price_filled = nth(price, 1)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-price_change) -> df2
```

Interesting part of example solution is at the end of df2.

```
> tail(df2, 20)
Source: local data frame [20 x 4]

    houseID year     price price_filled
 1       14 1995        NA           NA
 2       14 1996        NA           NA
 3       14 1997        NA           NA
 4       14 1998        NA           NA
 5       14 1999 0.8374778    0.8374778
 6       14 2000        NA    0.8374778
 7       14 2001        NA    0.8374778
 8       14 2002        NA    0.8374778
 9       14 2003 2.1918880    2.1918880
10       14 2004        NA    2.1918880
11       15 1995        NA           NA
12       15 1996 0.3982450    0.3982450
13       15 1997        NA    0.3982450
14       15 1998 1.7727000    1.7727000
15       15 1999        NA    1.7727000
16       15 2000        NA    1.7727000
17       15 2001        NA    1.7727000
18       15 2002 7.8636329    7.8636329
19       15 2003        NA    7.8636329
20       15 2004        NA    7.8636329
```

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` and `imputeTS` combination.

```
library(dplyr)
library(imputeTS)
df %>% group_by(houseID) %>% 
mutate(price = na.locf(price, na.remaining="keep"))
```

You could also replace `na.locf` with more advanced missing data replacement (imputation) functions from `imputeTS`. For example `na.interpolation` or `na.kalman`. For this just replace `na.locf` with the name of the function you like.

Answer (score 2):

Without `dplyr`:

```
  prices$price <-unlist(lapply(split(prices$price,prices$houseID),
function(x) zoo::na.locf(x,na.rm=FALSE)))

prices
   houseID year price
1        1 1995    NA
2        1 1996   100
3        1 1997   100
4        1 1998   120
5        1 1999   120
6        2 1995    NA
7        2 1996    NA
8        2 1997    NA
9        2 1998    30
10       2 1999    30
11       3 1995    NA
12       3 1996    44
13       3 1997    44
14       3 1998    44
15       3 1999    44
```

Comment: You should ad the `library(zoo)` in your code since you are using that library.

Answer (score 2):

Since [data.table v1.12.4](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1124--03-oct-2019), the package has a `nafill()` function, similar to `tidyr::fill()` or `zoo::na.locf()` and you can do:

```r
require(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[ , price := nafill(price, type = 'locf'), houseID ]
```

There is also `setnafill()`, though not allowing for a *group by*, but multiple columns.

```r
setnafill(df, type = 'locf', cols = 'price')
```

---

Data taken from @G. Grothendieck's answer:

```r
df = data.frame(houseID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                year = c(1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 1995L, 1996L,
                         1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L),
                price = c(NA, 100L, NA, 120L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30L, NA, NA, 44L,
                          NA, NA, NA))
```