# Filling missing levels

Tags: r, missing-data

I have the following type of dataframe:

```
Country <- rep(c("USA", "AUS", "GRC"),2)
Year    <- 2001:2006
Level   <- c("rich","middle","poor",rep(NA,3))
df <- data.frame(Country, Year,Level)

df 
Country Year  Level
1     USA 2001   rich
2     AUS 2002 middle
3     GRC 2003   poor
4     USA 2004   <NA>
5     AUS 2005   <NA>
6     GRC 2006   <NA>
```

I want to fill the missing values with the correct level label in the last from the right column.

So the expected outcome should be like this:

```
Country Year  Level
1     USA 2001   rich
2     AUS 2002 middle
3     GRC 2003   poor
4     USA 2004   rich
5     AUS 2005 middle
6     GRC 2006   poor
```

Comment: Related: [*Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value)

Comment: Also related: [_Replace missing values (NA) with most recent non-NA by group_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23340150/4497050)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can group by 'Country' and get the non-NA unique value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(Country) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(Level = Level[!is.na(Level)][1])
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Country [3]
#  Country  Year  Level
#   <fctr> <int> <fctr>
#1     USA  2001   rich
#2     AUS  2002 middle
#3     GRC  2003   poor
#4     USA  2004   rich
#5     AUS  2005 middle
#6     GRC  2006   poor
```

If we have loaded `dplyr` along with `plyr`, it is better to specify explicitly `dplyr::mutate` or `dplyr::summarise` so that it uses the function from `dplyr`.  There are same functions in `plyr` and it could potentially mask the functions from `dplyr` when both are loaded creating different behavior.

Comment: Nice thought. Good job. But aren't we not making an assumption here there will always be a non na unique value? Just trying to understand..

Comment: @AbdulRahmanK Thanks, It seems like the OP have a single unique value.  If there are multiple, values, perhaps `mutate(Level = toString(unique(Level[!is.na(Level)])))`

Comment: @akrun , I think your answer did not work. Even for the MWE I provided the outcome was not the expected one. because of this [1] and maps all countries to "rich". Tried to find a solution, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: @msh855 It is not clear. Based on the example, it is working

Comment: @akrun I don't know ! but when I use my example with your suggested code, the third column 'Level' is filled with only the value/level 'rich'. So, it is like replacing all values with this.

Comment: @msh855  As I mentioned, your example is working fine with this.  Is it possible that you also loaded `plyr`.  Try with `df %>% group_by(Country) %>% dplyr::mutate(Level = Level[!is.na(Level)][1])`

Comment: @akrun, ok you are right. once dplyr is updated it worked. But, let me trying now to my own dataframe. You have any idea why by loading dplyr it worked ?

Comment: @msh855  This is one of the problems of functions masking others.  the package `plyr` have `summarise/mutate` etc which could mask this dplyr `summarise/mutate` and when you call this, it could be calling the `plyr` mutate instead.  It is better to use `dplyr::` to specify that you wanted the function from that package.

Comment: @akrun finaly it worked. I re-accepted your answer. but, maybe you wish to update it making this point about dplyr more clear to everyone. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 13):

In base R, you could use `ave()`:

```
transform(df, Level = ave(Level, Country, FUN = na.omit))

#   Country Year  Level
# 1     USA 2001   rich
# 2     AUS 2002 middle
# 3     GRC 2003   poor
# 4     USA 2004   rich
# 5     AUS 2005 middle
# 6     GRC 2006   poor
```

Another, more accurate possibility is to use a join.  Here we merge the `Country` column with the NA-omitted data.  The outcome is the same, just in a different row order.

```
merge(df["Country"], na.omit(df))

#   Country Year  Level
# 1     AUS 2002 middle
# 2     AUS 2002 middle
# 3     GRC 2003   poor
# 4     GRC 2003   poor
# 5     USA 2001   rich
# 6     USA 2001   rich
```

Comment: I get this error message "Error in x[i] <- value[[j]] : replacement has length zero" when I apply it to my own dataframe

Answer (score 8):

You can do it using `data.table` and `zoo`:-

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df)
df[, Level := na.locf(Level), by = Country]
```

This will give you:-

```
   Country Year  Level
1:     USA 2001   rich
2:     AUS 2002 middle
3:     GRC 2003   poor
4:     USA 2004   rich
5:     AUS 2005 middle
6:     GRC 2006   poor
```

Answer (score 5):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  mutate(Level = replace(Level, is.na(Level), unique(na.omit(Level))))
```

> ```
>   Country  Year  Level
>    <fctr> <int> <fctr>
> 1     USA  2001   rich
> 2     AUS  2002 middle
> 3     GRC  2003   poor
> 4     USA  2004   rich
> 5     AUS  2005 middle
> 6     GRC  2006   poor
> ```

Or, more succinctly, applying @suchait's idea to use `na.locf`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  mutate(Level = zoo::na.locf(Level))
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Country) %>%
  fill(Level) %>%
  arrange(Year)
#   Country Year  Level
# 1     USA 2001   rich
# 2     AUS 2002 middle
# 3     GRC 2003   poor
# 4     USA 2004   rich
# 5     AUS 2005 middle
# 6     GRC 2006   poor
```

Comment: strrep(letters[23], 3)

Comment: @AidanGawronski  Cool! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `data.table` solution which *updates on join* using a *lookup table* which is created from the given dataset itself:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[!is.na(Level)], on = .(Country), Level := Level][]
```

> ```
>    Country Year  Level
> 1:     USA 2001   rich
> 2:     AUS 2002 middle
> 3:     GRC 2003   poor
> 4:     USA 2004   rich
> 5:     AUS 2005 middle
> 6:     GRC 2006   poor
> ```