# fill missing values with value from previous column

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` whit some columns with missing values, and I want that the missing values are filled in with data from a previous column. For example:

```
country <- c('a','b','c')
yr01 <- c(15,16,7)
yr02 <- c(NA,18,NA)
yr03 <- c(20,22,NA)
yr04 <- c(15,18,19)

tab <- data.frame(country,yr01,yr02,yr03,yr04)
tab

  country yr01 yr02 yr03 yr04
1       a   15   NA   20   15
2       b   16   18   22   18
3       c    7   NA   NA   19
```

How can I make it so that the `NA` are replaced by the previous value? For example, in country `a` column `yr02` will be equals to **15**, and in country `c` columns `year02` and `yr03` will be **7**. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually easier to work with columns, but we can `apply` to rows the standard answer from the R-FAQ [Replace NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7735681/903061).

```
tab[-1] = t(apply(tab[-1], 1, zoo::na.locf))
tab
#   country yr01 yr02 yr03 yr04
# 1       a   15   15   20   15
# 2       b   16   18   22   18
# 3       c    7    7    7   19
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor, but it seems that the values changed. Look at country c for example.

Comment: Sorry, needed to transpose the result. Fixed now.

Comment: By the way Gregor, if I had the data in columns, like column country, year and data. How would I fill the missing values, BY country? Thanks!

Comment: Generally, you can use `dplyr` or `data.table` to easily do anything by group. Here's a complete question on filling NA by group: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23340150/903061