# Is there a "fill-up" or "fill-down" command in r?

Tags: r, data-munging

Is it possible to "fill up" NA values based on a condition in two other columns?

A similar answer is found here:
[Replace missing values (NA) with most recent non-NA by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340150/replace-missing-values-na-with-most-recent-non-na-by-group)

This question is different because I need the fill up to be based on the values of another column and the value above the value in said column.  Explanation below.

I have a dataframe and I need something that looks at the value above and the value beside and the value above that to evaluate.  The process should go like this:
x = value that is not null.

*if value above x is null and*

*value beside x is the same as the value above the value of x then*

*fill up.*

Here is some example code from `mtcars`

```
mtcars1 <- as_tibble(mtcars)

mtcars1 <- mtcars1 %>%
  select(cyl, mpg, disp, hp) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  arrange(cyl, disp)


ex <- rep("NA", length(mtcars1$cyl))

mtcars1$ex=ex 

mtcars1$ex <- if_else(mtcars$cyl = 4 & mtcars$disp > 100, ex==31.4, ex)

mtcars1$ex <- sapply(mtcars1, function(x) ifelse((mtcars1$cyl <= 4 && 
mtcars$disp > 100), 23.5, "NA"))
```

See the picture below.  I want `23.5` to fill up until the values in the "cyl" column change.  So,

if value above is NULL()

and cyl value = cyl value above,

fill up.

[image]

Is this possible in R?

Comment: See `zoo::na.locf`

Comment: also `tidyr::fill`