# Is there a equivalent for the tidyr fill() for strings in R?

Tags: r, string, tidyr

So I have a data frame like this one:

```
First Group  Bob
             Joe
             John
             Jesse
Second Group Jane
             Mary
             Emily
             Sarah
             Grace
```

I would like to fill in the empty cells in the first column in the data frame with the last string in that column i.e

```
First Group  Bob
First Group  Joe
First Group  John
First Group  Jesse
Second Group Jane
Second Group Mary
Second Group Emily
Second Group Sarah
Second Group Grace
```

With tidyr, there is fill() but it obviously doesn't work with strings. Is there an equivalent for strings? If not is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work with character columns?

Comment: Testing it gives me `Error in UseMethod("fill_") : 
  no applicable method for 'fill_' applied to an object of class "character"`, even though `?fill` says it takes atomic vectors. You can do something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340150/replace-missing-values-na-with-most-recent-non-na-by-group

Comment: `fill` fills missing values, i.e. `NA`. Are your "empty cells" `NA`, or `""` ('blank' `character`); note the difference between `c("a", "", "b")` and `c("a", NA, "b")`. `fill(data.frame(x = c("a", "", "b")), x)`; `fill(data.frame(x = c("a", NA, "b")), x)`

Comment: Probably relevant here: check the `na.strings` argument in `read.table`.

Comment: It would help us understand your data if you can please include a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) The easiest and recommended way to that is to use  `dput()` to give your example data with structure.  That way it makes it easy for those who want to help and you'll greatly increase your chances of better/faster/more numerous responses.

Comment: Searching for a way to fill `NA` in a **character *vector*** took me here; but the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value). TL;DR check out the `zoo::na.locf`  and similar `zoo::na.___` options

Answer (score 20):

Seems `fill()` is designed to be used in isolation. When using `fill()` inside a `mutate()` statement this error appears (regardless of the data type), but it works when using it as just a component of the pipe structure. Could that have been the problem?

Just for full clarity, a quick example. Assuming you have a data frame called 'people' with columns 'group' and 'name', the right structure would be:

```
people %>%
    fill(group)
```

and the following would give the error you described (and a similar error when using numbers):

```
people %>%
    mutate(
        group = fill(group)
    )
```

Comment: This can work if you introduce the data input to the function (here as "."): ```people %>% mutate(group = fill(., group))```  Typically this is extraneous, though people may want the original column for comparison: ```people %>%  mutate(group_fill = fill(.,group))```

Answer (score 1):

(I made the assumption that this was output from an R console session. If it's a raw text file the data input may need to be done with `read.fwf`.)

The display suggests those are empty character values in the "spaces">

First set them to NA and then use na.locf from zoo:

```
 dat[dat==""] <- NA
 dat[1:2] <- lapply(dat[1:2], zoo::na.locf)
 dat
#------------
      V1    V2    V3
1  First Group   Bob
2  First Group   Joe
3  First Group  John
4  First Group Jesse
5 Second Group  Jane
6 Second Group  Mary
7 Second Group Emily
8 Second Group  Sara
9 Second Group Grace
```

To start with what I was using:

```
dat <-
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("", "First", "Second"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Group"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(1L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 3L), .Label = c("Bob", 
    "Emily", "Grace", "Jane", "Jesse", "Joe", "John", "Mary", 
    "Sara"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have to take a stab at what your data structure is, I might have something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(c1=c("First Group", "", "", "", "Second Group", "", "", "", ""),
                 c2=c("Bob","Joe","Jon","Jesse","Jane","Mary","Emily","Sara","Grace"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then, a very basic way to do this would be by simply looping:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) if(df$c1[i]=="") df$c1[i] <- df$c1[i-1]  

df

            c1    c2
1  First Group   Bob
2  First Group   Joe
3  First Group   Jon
4  First Group Jesse
5 Second Group  Jane
6 Second Group  Mary
7 Second Group Emily
8 Second Group  Sara
9 Second Group Grace
```

However, I would suggest you accept @42-'s solution if you have anything other than a small data set as `zoo::na.locf` is optimized to work with large numbers of records and is a very respected, widely used stable package.