# create column based on last non missing value of other column

Tags: r, dplyr

very similar to this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340150/replace-missing-values-na-with-most-recent-non-na-by-group)  I try to populate a new variable by finding the last non missing value by group for an existing variable in a dataframe, ideally using dplyr/zoo. I want to only keep the last value though, and not merely overwrite missings, consider the following minimal example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID   = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2,2),
                  date = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  var1 = c('a', '', 'b', '','c', ''))

df2 = ## R-commands to get:
df2 <- data.frame(ID   = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2,2),
                  date = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  var1 = c('b', 'b', 'b', 'c','c', 'c'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(var1 = last(var1[var1 != '']))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 3
> # Groups:   ID [2]
>      ID  date var1 
>   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
> 1     1     1 b    
> 2     1     2 b    
> 3     1     3 b    
> 4     2     1 c    
> 5     2     2 c    
> 6     2     3 c
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `base R` using `ave`

```
df1$var1 <- with(df1, ave(as.character(var1), ID, FUN = 
      function(x) tail(x[nzchar(x)], 1)))
df1$var1
#[1] "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
```